# Is this caused by attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, attr-accessible

I just lately update my model with `attr_accessible` fields and suddenly some tests would not work, as i would expect. However, i have a spec like:

```
context "when user buys a game item" do
  let(:inventory) {@user.inventory << Factory(:inventory)}

  it "should present an error if the id ..." do
    GameItem.stub(:find_by_id).and_return(Factory(:game_item))
    @user.inventory.should == 1  # TEST
    post :buy, :id => (game_item.id + 1)
    flash[:error].should == I18n.t('error.invalid_post')
    response.should redirect_to melee_url('Weapon')
  end
end
```

The line `@user.inventory.should == 1` is just a check that i made now. The inventory is `nil` for some reason. Does this happen because of the `<<` operation? I would guess that this is most probable, due to the inventory_id attribute of the User model.

I have to say that `attr_accessible` generally seems like a hack to me and i kinda don't like it, though i can see why it should be used. Do you think this is the case? If so, how can i stay clear of that check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is lazy; it won't call the block unless the variable you're defining is used, and I don't see you accessing `inventory` anywhere. You access `@user.inventory`, but that's not the same thing.

Either lose the `let` definition and just put it in your `it` block, or make sure you call it first before you make sure it did what it was supposed to.

Comment: yes, i actually fixed it, was a mixture of things going on, including @user.inventory. thanx :)